# .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting ,EventType clr20r3,system.invalidoperationexception

Tags: vb.net, events, exception, clr, .net-framework-version

Recently I developed one VB.NET utility.It worked properly in my development and Test environment.Once I moved it to Production this utility did not worked.Every time it is giving me same error in System's application log.The error is

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Event Category: None
Event ID:   5000
Date:       25/09/2013
Time:       9:21:04 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   FWCHAPPLIVE
Description:
EventType clr20r3, P1 ncbrevfilesftp.exe, P2 0.0.0.0, P3 52425c5c, P4 ncbrevfilesftp,
P5 0.0.0.0, P6 52425c5c, P7 

b, P8 ca, P9 system.invalidoperationexception, P10 NIL.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at 

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

I am not able to find out exact reason behind this.Please help me.What would be the cause of this issue.Utility is not even hitting public sub Main (Entry Point).

For your information

```
Server := Win 2003
.NET Framework := 2.0.0.0
Utility Developed in VB.NET (VS 2005)
```

Please help.Thanks in advance...